# Getting Fatal Error on DynamicLinkComponents Object in Firebase-DeepLinking Pod

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, deep-linking

Xcode version: 10.1
Firebase SDK version: 6.0.0
Firebase Component: Firebase/DynamicLinks
Component version: 4.0.0

Hi, I am stuck at a point in firebase-Deeplinking when dealing with deep linking, it has been enabled before and was working fine, then God knows how did I got ShortUrl nil, after some RND, I did managed to update pods and then all happens that when instancing DynamicLinkComponents with its initialiser.

I have tried all of the mentioned or unmentioned situations over internet,

> clean build, plus deleted Derived Data,
>
> reinstall Pods.
>
> updated Cocoapods then updated pods again.

```
let components = DynamicLinkComponents(link: urlLink, domainURIPrefix: AppConstants.kDynamicLink_Domain)!
```

both urlLink and AppConstants.kDynamicLink_Domain have values in them but still getting app crashed, with Fatal error that nil found while unwrapping.
I want it not to be nil and pursue my code.
I have no idea why its happening. but I have seen some other issues which does not relate to mine so I believe its not duplicate.

Comment: put that code `guard let` instead of using a !, this won't solve the issue but you got a fallback in case you got `nil`, does the `domainURIPrefix` is config on firebase?

Comment: okay, got it. And yes it is config, not from firebase

Comment: hi anything else you got for me.